# Why is the Reference section not numbered when I use number_sections: true with R Markdown for PDF output?

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

I'm trying to generate a PDF document with numbered sections, citations, and a bibliography from R Markdown using `rmarkdown::render`. It works fine except that the References section is not numbered.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document: 
    number_sections: true
references:
- id: fenner2012a
  title: One-click science marketing
  author:
  - family: Fenner
    given: Martin
---

# Introduction
See [@fenner2012a].

# References
```

I would expect rendering this to result in:

```
1. Introduction
See (Fenner 2012).

2. References
Fenner, Martin. n.d. “One-Click Science Marketing.”
```

But instead I get (note that References is missing a section number):

```
1. Introduction
See (Fenner 2012).

References
Fenner, Martin. n.d. “One-Click Science Marketing.”
```

Any ideas?

Comment: By default the Reference section is not numbered. Out of the box I see no easy solution to change that except using an own format.

Comment: @J_F, thanks! But I guess it should be, or am I missing something? So a better idea would be to file this as an issue on https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Rmd syntax `# Headername`, use LaTeX syntax `\section{Headername}` for headers (`\subsection{}` == `##`, for subsections). This works for me.